# Driver Install Package project type is missing in Visual Studio 2015

Tags: visual-studio-2015

I have installed WDK and SDK for VS 2015. But when I try to create Driver Install Package project did not find option to create it.

[image: screen shot of visual studio new project dialog box.]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You must first install VS2015, then install WDK10.